# TypeError: Class constructor MixinStrategy cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: typescript, jwt, passport.js, nestjs

I was following along with the jwt example like found here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication. I copied and pasted the example. After npm installing the necessary bits and bops I got this error which does not occur in the sample which I just copied. Of which I have no idea what it means! Anyone any ideas?

```
TypeError: Class constructor MixinStrategy cannot be invoked without 'new'

   8 | export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
   9 |   constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
> 10 |     super({
  11 |       jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  12 |       secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
  13 |     });

  at new JwtStrategy (data/auth/strategies/jwt.strategy.ts:10:5)
  at resolveConstructorParams (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:64:84)
  at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:86:30)
```

Comment: Can you provide a way to replicate the problem - a repo, etc? Could be specific to package versions or whatever.

Comment: Sure, clone this folder https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/19-auth npm i && npm start it will show up, on windows 10 and node 8.11.2

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the error you've got. There's no problem with MixinStrategy. Your current code likely differs from the one you've linked. But I've got problems with typings. I'd suggest to open an issue regarding this example (19-auth misses @types/passport-jwt dependency) in https://github.com/nestjs/nest  and in https://github.com/nestjs/passport regarding improper PassportStrategy type. Any way, I wasn't able to make this example workable; the server runs but responds with 404.

Comment: Not sure if anything can be done at this point. I was seriously considering NestJS as my next framework but it seems it is just not mature enough. The documentation is somewhat lacking and examples that don't work out of the box don't really help. Thanks for bringing this problem to SO, this was eye-opening.

Comment: no my code was the sample code, bit for bit the same. I cloned the sample in my project but the error was there before I could change anything. anyhow I used this https://github.com/bojidaryovchev/nest-angular to fix it.Nest is a great framework that is if you love angular and the little problems it has are hardly unovercomable. You should try it for sure.

Comment: Yes, the resemblance with Angular makes it easy to adopt but the issue with `any` type seems a bit off for TS-oriented framework, Angular typing is much more solid. Thanks for a boilerplate link, I'll give it a try.

Comment: check your tsconfig.json to ensure "target" is "es6"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [project](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/19-auth) lacks `@types/passport-jwt` typings, so they should be additionally installed:

```
npm i -D @types/passport-jwt
```

This results in

> src\auth\jwt.strategy.ts (10,6): Call target does not contain any signatures. (2346)

error, because `@nestjs/passport` wasn't properly typed; [`PassportStrategy` return type is `any`](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/e42ffb1739e792dc48aafd73ab18e7d0040e06ac/lib/passport.strategy.ts#L11).

In order to fix this,

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
...
```

should be changed to:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AbstractStrategy, PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
...
const PassportJwtStrategy: new(...args) => AbstractStrategy & Strategy = PassportStrategy(Strategy);

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportJwtStrategy {
...
```

Comment: This issue is fixed in `1.0.11` patch release.

Comment: Both the original code and this throws "TypeError: Class constructor MixinStrategy cannot be invoked without 'new'" when setting the "target" to "ES5" in tsconfig.json. Is there a way for ES5? @estus

Comment: @Smartkid I would expect that for ES5 target because TS uses established recipe for inheritance, `_this = Parent.call(this)`. It's expected that entire class hierarchy is transpiled to make it work, otherwise this will result in an error because native classes cannot be called without `new`. Why would you use ES5 target in Node any way?

Comment: @estus Thanks for your explanation. I use yarn workspace to share come code between a nestjs server project and a react based project (which targets to ES5 to avoid babel). The Jest support of older versions of WebStorm seems to run unit-tests using the tsconfig under the workspace root directory and ignores the tsconfig under sub projects. It looks like the WebStorm fixed this issue in 2018.1.4 .

Comment: @Smartkid Thanks for the information regarding Webstorm, good to know,

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was in tsconfig.ts file, I'm using nest.js and after cli command `typeorm init` it overwrite tsconfig so `npm run start:dev` was throwing exception: **TypeError: Class constructor MixinStrategy cannot be invoked without 'new'**

note: is also overwrites package.json with older version of `typescipt, @ts/node, ts-node`

Answer (score 0):

- Change the typescript target to any later version than es6 e.g ES2017, ES2018, ES2019 etc.
- You can check out the conversation at https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2190#issuecomment-492150156

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32853510)